# How to get your webapp to interact with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-chrome-extension, flutter-web

I have this project where I need my webapp to talk to a chrome extension. The documentation to get your webapp to send requests to this chrome extension is unfortunately for javascipt. So I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to the equivalent feature in flutter (library or methods).

Here is the documented way of sending requests to the chrome extention:
https://www.icondev.io/docs/chrome-extension-connect